# Move different file types to separate folders

Tags: command-line, batch

I have a large collection of photos in separate folders for each event e.g. holiday in Italy, holiday in France for example.

Within each folder e.g. `P:\Italy` there are multiple file types: JPEG, CR2, MOV.

How could I separate thes files so I end up with the following

`P:\Italy\JPEG`
`P:\Italy\CR2`
`P:\Italy\MOV`

I have multiple sets of photos in my `P:\` drive so any script will have to recurively go through each folder and create the subfolders also.

Comment: We have a lot of questions regarding moving files already. What have you tried so far? Where are you having trouble? What problems have you found? Have you tried to search: https://superuser.com/search?q=move+type+to+folder or https://superuser.com/search?q=file+type+to+folder+batch

Comment: Absolutely minimally without batch you can easily sort by file type in Explorer, create the relevant folders and then simply select all files in the group of types. Or you can use the search tool in the top right of every Explorer window, enter a type ("\*.jpg") then Ctrl-a, Ctrl-x, then go to the folder and Ctrl-v. There are *many* solutions to this problem and it is up to you to help narrow down what you are trying to do.

Comment: Mokubai - I have maybe 250 folders I need to do this in, so can't do manually

Comment: I've added a third dupe with "structure". I'm not saying to do it manually, I'm saying that you need to have shown research and effort as we have a lot of various solutions. Show us why various attempts have not worked so far. We are not a script writing service.